# Magento how to checkout one product from the customer dashboard

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, customer-account, php-5.4, virtual-products

I have a product whose price is 100$ and its a virtual product. I want to show that product in customer dashboard as a button and if customer clicks the button then he will be going for a checkout process of $100. I want the product should go to checkout from the customer dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override a `CartController` and add a new action named `addvirtualAction()`. Copy all code from default `addAction()` to `addvirtualAction()` and replace following block:

```
if (!$cart->getQuote()->getHasError()) {
    $message = $this->__('%s was added to your shopping cart.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($product->getName()));
    $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($message);
}
```

WITH :

```
if (!$cart->getQuote()->getHasError()) {
    /* REDIRECT TO CHECKOUT FROM HERE */
}
```

Now you have to set that PRODUCT BUTTON url as

```
$this->getUrl("checkout/cart/addvirtual", array("product"=> $product->getId(), "form_key" => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ))
```

this will generate url like: `http://127.0.0.1/mage1921/checkout/cart/addvirtual/product/1/form_key/nyhjZWTTLQ3pcj2F/`

**UPDATE:**  For multiple quantities use this code:

```
$this->getUrl("checkout/cart/addvirtual", array("product"=> $product->getId(), "qty"=> NO_OF_QUANTITY, "form_key" => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ))
```

That's it...

By another way, you can use observer that dispatches after product is added to cart for redirecting to CHECKOUT page

Comment: Are you sure that it will not add to cart the product.

Comment: This will add product to cart and redirects to CHECKOUT page

Comment: it will show the cart page in frontend or not. I dont want to show the cart page.

Comment: No it'll not show CART page. When you click PRODUCT BUTTON on customer dashboard, this product will be added to cart and page will be redirected directly to CHECKOUT. Cart page will be skipped

Comment: Thanks a lot, if any queries are there I will comment below.

Comment: Can you please help in increasing the quantity of that 100$ product with one variable.

Comment: check answer updated

Comment: Just i have to add that last code on the href of my submit button right.

Comment: if (!$cart->getQuote()->getHasError()) {
    /* REDIRECT TO CHECKOUT FROM HERE */
}
inside i have to write anything or it will be blank

Comment: While adding to cart it is redirecting to cart page and showing 0 in price column and subtotal columns

Comment: You have to replace `/* REDIRECT TO CHECKOUT FROM HERE */` WITH `$this->_redirect('checkout');`

Comment: after this also it is redirecting to checkout/cart with the product but not the price. Help me in getting the price of the product

Comment: can you post your PRODUCT BUTTON's url ?

Comment: Yes it is taking me to checkout/cart with that product but the price is not coming

Comment: I mean, can you show your PRODUCT BUTTON's url here ?

Comment: "https://diastage.ddns.net:8443/diakart/checkout/cart/addvirtual/product/1710/qty/1/price/100.0000/form_key/2Z3ZzsMkyC93rUz8/" i am getting this url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39497/discussion-between-anil-suthar-and-asheem-patro).

Comment: I am getting the above url for the PRODUCT BUTTON

Comment: are you sure it's calling `addvirtual` Action ?

Comment: I am not sure which action it is calling. But the product button contains a submit button and already having one action for the submit button. I am not able to add two actions for one form submit.